# $f\in L^2(\mathbb{R})\Rightarrow f\to 0, x\to\pm\infty$?

Tags: functions, lebesgue-integral

As the title already suggests: Let $f\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$. Does this imply that
$$
f\to 0\text{ as }x\to\pm\infty?
$$

Comment: No! Let the graph of $f$ have a bunch of tall skinny bumps.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean?

Answer (score 4):

The answer is no.
Consider $$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \chi_{[n-\frac 1 {n^2},n+\frac 1 {n^2} ]}(x)$$

With $\chi$ the charasteristic function. $f$ is in $L^2$ but $f$ does not have a limit at $\infty$. You can also find similar examples which create a continuous function.

Comment: As is, that's not an $L^2$-function. You should make the intervals smaller, e.g. $\chi_{[n-\tfrac{1}{n^2},n+\tfrac{1}{n^2}]}$.